# Way to write new filename on wildcard input?

Tags: shell, awk, filenames, wildcards

I have some experience with Inix terminals from science internships I've been part of, mainly using a few utilities like `grep`, `awk`, and `sed` but there is one thing I've been trying to figure out for a while that would really make me far more efficient with the number crunching I have to do.

I have a script `run.awk` that performs some manipulations on a large of collection of massive text files. As it is it will take the file `chloride.out`, extract data from it and write `chloride.cm` .

Is there anyway I can make this script take in `*.out` and write `*.cm` files based off the initial wildcard phrase in shell?

The amount of scripts I've written for processing large amounts of data that I've had to do a hundred+ iterations of is just annoying.

Ideally I would like to know if there is a way that I can do this for all my scripts with something via the shell. If it can't be automated in the shell or an equivalent can I least automate my `awk` scripts in a similar manner as I've described?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You most certainly can make awk deal with multiple files via wildcards. One suggestion would be to leave the `run.awk` as a generic "function" that takes a single file in and produces a single output file, and then call it from another script which could then take care of assimilating the input and output files.

#### Example

This would be a Bash script, we can call it, `awk_runner.bash`.

```
#!/bin/bash

for ifname in *.out; do 
  ofname=${ifname/.out/.cm}
  printf "IN: %s, OUT: %s\n" $ifname $ofname
  printf "running run.awk with %s & %s\n\n" $ifname $ofname

  run.awk $ifname $ofname
done
```

#### Sample run

I made a example directory with some test files in it.

```
$ touch file{1..4}.out
```

This resulted in 4 files being made:

```
$ ls -1
file1.out
file2.out
file3.out
file4.out
```

Now we run our script:

```
$ ./awk_runner.bash
IN: file1.out, OUT: file1.cm
running run.awk with file1.out & file1.cm

IN: file2.out, OUT: file2.cm
running run.awk with file2.out & file2.cm

IN: file3.out, OUT: file3.cm
running run.awk with file3.out & file3.cm

IN: file4.out, OUT: file4.cm
running run.awk with file4.out & file4.cm
```

After each line that starts with, "running..." our script could run from here.

#### Files in a list

Say instead of using the wildcard, `*.out` we instead had a file with a list of filenames in it, say:

```
$ cat filelist.txt 
file1.out
file2.out
file3.out
file4.out
```

We could use this modified version of our script which would use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop. Now let's call this variant of the script, `awk_file_runner.bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read ifname; do 
  ofname=${ifname/.out/.cm}
  printf "IN: %s, OUT: %s\n" $ifname $ofname
  printf "running run.awk with %s & %s\n\n" $ifname $ofname

  run.awk $ifname $ofname
done < filelist.txt
```

This version of the script reads the input from the file, `filelist.txt`:

```
done < filelist.txt
```

Then for each turn of the `while` loop, we're using the `read` command to read in a line from the input file.

```
while read ifname; do
```

It then performs everything in the same way as the first script where it will run the `awk` script `run.awk` as it loops through each line of the file.

Comment: is there anyway i can also abstractualize this one step further, and feed this bash script the scripts from a file. I don't need it for this application but it might come in handy somewhere. Also I would delete that arrow right by run.awk right?

Comment: @user507974 - yes I removed the comment from the script, sorry if that was confusing you. It now only shows what you'd need. Of course you could run this using names from a file instead. I'll add that as a 2nd example.

Comment: @user507974 - see updates, let me know if you have any other questions about this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than writing a shell wrapper and spawning a new awk instance for every file you process, you can do this in awk directly.  If you already have an awk script, you can access the current file using the FILENAME variable.  So, if you run `awk 'some commands' file1 file2`, you can tell if you're working with file1 or file2 using FILENAME.  You can also use `>` on `print`/`printf` in awk.  So, if you have an awk script like

```
/pattern/{ print $1,$3 }
```

you could easily do

```
/pattern/{ print $1,$3 > FILENAME".processed" }
```

or use `FNR=1` to tell when you're in a new file, and create a variable to do more complex manipulation on the filename.  Like replacing a `.in` extension with `.out`, as in

```
sauer@humpy:/tmp$ grep . file*.in
file1.in:a
file1.in:b
file2.in:c
sauer@humpy:/tmp$ awk 'FNR=1{out=FILENAME;sub("\.in$",".out",out)} {print "processed"$0 > out}' file*.in
sauer@humpy:/tmp$ grep . file*.out
file1.out:processeda
file1.out:processedb
file2.out:processedc
```

I'm using `grep .` to show the filename and the contents of multiple files here, which is also a fun trick.  But the important thing is setting the value of the `out` variable to a modified version of `FILENAME` when `FNR` changes to 1 (so we're on line 1 of the file), and then redirecting all prints to `out`.  Note that this is mildly dangerous, in that failure to match the extension will result in no substitution, leading to overwriting your input files.  So, it'd be good to add in a fail-safe check to make sure that `out != FILENAME` or something like that as well.  That's left as an exercise for the reader. ;)

If you need a file containing a list of filenames, it's easiest to just run it like

```
awkscript $(< /path/to/filename_list_file )
```

Which takes the contents of the `filename_list_file` and puts it on the command line.